# AppEngine Simple Hello World Application ERROR

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to upload my app using Google App Engine Launcher. And here's what I got but when I tried the URL on the browser, it works.

I don't know what caused this:

```
2013-10-03 21:01:57 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=vs.barter@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', u'C:\\Users\\userpc\\Dropbox\\code\\web\\barter-app']"
09:02 PM Host: appengine.google.com
09:02 PM Application: volkovasystems-barter-app; version: 1
09:02 PM 
Starting update of app: volkovasystems-barter-app, version: 1
09:02 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for vs.barter@gmail.com: 09:02 PM Scanning files on local disk.
09:02 PM Cloning 366 application files.
09:02 PM Uploading 56 files and blobs.
09:04 PM Uploaded 56 files and blobs
09:04 PM Compilation starting.
09:04 PM Compilation completed.
09:04 PM Starting deployment.
09:05 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
2013-10-03 21:05:16,249 ERROR appcfg.py:2120 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2101, in DoUpload
    app_summary = self.Commit()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1809, in Commit
    lambda: (self.IsReady(), None), PrintRetryMessage, 1, 2, 60, 20)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 430, in RetryWithBackoff
    done, opaque_value = callable_func()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1809, in <lambda>
    lambda: (self.IsReady(), None), PrintRetryMessage, 1, 2, 60, 20)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1884, in IsReady
    result = self.Send('/api/appversion/isready')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1555, in Send
    return self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 387, in do_open
    raise url_error
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
09:05 PM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 184, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 180, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4403, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4394, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2469, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4103, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3051, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml, yaml_file_basename)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3000, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2101, in DoUpload
    app_summary = self.Commit()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1809, in Commit
    lambda: (self.IsReady(), None), PrintRetryMessage, 1, 2, 60, 20)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 430, in RetryWithBackoff
    done, opaque_value = callable_func()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1809, in <lambda>
    lambda: (self.IsReady(), None), PrintRetryMessage, 1, 2, 60, 20)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1884, in IsReady
    result = self.Send('/api/appversion/isready')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1555, in Send
    return self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 387, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
2013-10-03 21:05:24 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

This is the app.yaml file:

```
application: volkovasystems-barter-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.application
```

This is the helloworld application:

```
import webapp2


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World! FROM GOOGLE APP ENGINE MOFOS!')


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Try adding `libraries:\n
- name: webapp2\n
  version: latest` to your app.yaml. (\n indicates newlines, since SO comments can't have line breaks)

Comment: I got this error. I just ran the script again and it worked the second time without my changing anything.

Comment: just change `version` to another name in `app.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

You can look this: https://code.google.com/p/goagent/issues/detail?id=12542
You may run another python process ,kill it.